# Google Gemini API response

Tags: python, google-gemini

I am using the Gemini API, and need some help. When I ran my code that I got from the docs it returned:

`<google.generativeai.types.generation_types.GenerateContentResponse>` .
Here is my code

```
import pathlib
import textwrap

import google.generativeai as genai

from IPython.display import display
from IPython.display import Markdown


def to_markdown(text):
  text = text.replace('•', '  *')
  return Markdown(textwrap.indent(text, '> ', predicate=lambda _: True))


genai.configure(api_key='AN API KEY WAS HERE')

model = genai.GenerativeModel('gemini-pro')
response = model.generate_content("What is the meaning of life?")
print(response)
```

I ran this, and got the response above.

Comment: What "error" are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say response. I updated it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a google object of the response you are getting.
You need to mention as response.text to get the actual text.

Like this:

```
print(response.text)
```